# Web Api 2 Download XML as File not just content in browser

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api2

I currently have the following that downloads xml as content on screen

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetAllMemberParty()
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.addressTypeRepository.GetAll(), Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
```

Is it possible to add a quick one liner to make this download as a file? Rather than write my own IHttpActionResult implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following makes it download as a file but without any extension. I'd prefer it to have an extension but seems a bit of a hassle to create my own http response that returns a file?

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.repository.GetAll(), Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
    }
```

I found a better solution to this problem. The ResponseMessage method is part of the API controller. This implements the IHttpActionResult so you can do the following:

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnList, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
                    responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                    responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Address.json";
                    return ResponseMessage(responseMsg);
```

You could of course just use and return a HTTPResponseMessage!